# Simple problem of combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

There are $3$ red socks, $4$ green socks and $3$ blue socks.You choose $2$ socks. The probability that they are of the same color is

Answer:
$\dfrac{^{3}C_{2}+^{4}C_{2}+^{3}C_{2}}{^{10}C_{2}}=\dfrac{4}{15}$

But my approach was to $1-$all unfavorable cases

$i.e.$

$1-\dfrac{RED*GREEN + GREEN*BLUE + RED*BLUE}{^{10}C_{2}}$ = $1-\dfrac{3*4 + 4*3 + 3*3}{^{10}C_{2}}$ = $\dfrac{11}{30}$

I am not able to identify my mistake, it will be suffice if some one can provide a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have an arithmetic error when computing $1 - \dfrac{3\cdot4+4\cdot3+3\cdot3}{10 \choose 2} = 4 / 15$.